# MacBook Air Kensington Lock Alternative

Tags: macbook-pro, security

The MacBook Air has no Kensington lock slot. What other options are available for  protecting it from theft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plugspy](http://www.celmaro.com/plugspy/) by Celmaro claims to secure a MacBook Air by monitoring its MagSafe connection status:

> Plug Spy au­to ac­ti­vates when your screen is locked and start an an­noy­ing high vol­ume alert sound and send a Growl no­ti­fi­ca­tion when your Mac­Book gets un­plugged from the MagSafe pow­er adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one USB option. Haven't tested it personally, though, but seems better than some of the alternatives involving plastic shells and such.

[http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F5L013-Laptop-Security-Alarm/dp/B000RPVHDC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RPVHDC)

Answer (score 1):

I like a good old hardware solution, just a basic lock/ case. I ordered the below macbook air lock. It worked! the bottom part has a built in security lock and you get a cable with it.

Check it out: http://www.maclocks.com/macbook-air-lock/macbookairlock-13.html

Answer (score 0):

This security solution from Multplx works with all laptops, there is no need for a Kensington lock slot as their solution secures via the audio port. You can buy just the Anchor adaptor on its own or adaptor and cable lock. I use it for my macbook and its got really good reviews from users of many other laptops too.

https://store.multplx.com/collections/laptops/products/universal-laptop-security-lock-system